# Элементы recyclerView при скрулинге растягиваются в высоту

Tags: android, xml, recyclerview

Есть разметка со списком фильмов(в recyclerView). При запуске приложения, список отображается корректно, но если начинаю скрулить вниз/вверх то элементы растягиваются в высоту. Подскажите пожалуйста где мой промах.
Код разметки:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/title"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/genre"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textColor="@color/year" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: По логике, элемент `RecyclerView` должен и без скролла на весь экран растягиваться, обратите внимание на атрибуты корневого `view` Вашей `layout`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря комментарию **post_zeew** обратил внимание на `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, именно значение wrap_content должно было быть проставлено.

Comment: Только вот непонятно, как оно у Вас нормально отображалась при запуске приложения.

Comment: @post_zeew Изначально были пункты в порядке, но когда прокручивал их вниз к примеру а потом резко наверх, то они уже растягивались.